# specify the result of a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, return

Am not sure if functions in javascript are what we call `methods` in other programming languages.Methods in other programming languages can have their result specified just after the `access-specifier` like in `C#` for example i would do like

```
//method to return int
private int myinteger(){
     int a=0;
    return  a;
}
//method to return string
private string mystring(){
   string b="myreturn";
   return b;
}
```

I just don't know how to do that with javascript functions, you think you can help me with a sample?Thank You very much :)

Comment: please lookup the difference between statically typed (like c#) and dynamically typed languages (like javascript)

Comment: Long-story short: there is no such thing in Javascript. If you desire type safety, i strongly recommend to use Typescript instead. Just beware that this comes with some complexity in setup - depending on your use case.

Comment: Will sure do that, i just want to learn, in the mean time can you help me with code to specify the result?

Comment: Okay thats all thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with javascript, but you still have two workarounds available:

1. Use eslint and use the https://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return rule
2. Use typescript

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to provide the `data types` in `javascript`. The `functions` are pretty similar you just have to start it with the `function` keyword.

Also, we need to start the variables with `const` or `let`.

I use the `console.log(myinteger());` below to log the value of the `myinteger()` function in the browser console. (Similar to `c++`'s `cout`)

```js
//method to return int
function myinteger() {
  const a = 0;
  return a;
}
//method to return string
function mystring() {
  const b = "myreturn";
  return b;
}

console.log(myinteger());
console.log(mystring());
```

If you are someone who wants to use javascript but still want to assign the data type and many more thing then you can use [TypeScript By Microsoft](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has types for values (not variables)

so you can define a variable as

```
var name = "Hamond";
```

and to know it's type you have to use `typeof`

```
typeof name; // "string"
```

Side note: you can use `let` or `const` instead of `var` but let that be for another time.

so variables in javascript doesn't have types, values have.
You can add static typing using `typescript` so

```
var name: string = "Hamond";
```

and at dev time if you wanted to edit `name` and incorrectly deal with it as a non `string` type you will get an error
warning you immediately

```
name = 3; // error
name - 4; // error
// and so forth because `name` is of `string` type
```

so this type check is done at `author` or `dev` time and you don't have to wait until run time to get the error.

---

Why all the talk about variables and values?

Because Javascript function can return any value(even returning a variable is basically returning its value if it's scalar value or its reference if it's an object type)

so defining a function look like:

```
function doSomething(){

    return 33;
}
```

notes:

- no return type
- can have no return statement(by default will return `undefined`)

with `typescript`

```
function doSomething(): number{

    return 33;
}
```

typing problems solved at dev/write time

About `function` vs `method`:
I think developers in many times use these terms interchangeably, but in `javascript` we just have `function`, even a function defined inside a class in javascript is just a `function`. People like the name `method` when its defined inside some class.

references:

[JS syntax](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md)

[The Nature Of Functions](https://github.com/getify/Functional-Light-JS/blob/master/manuscript/ch2.md/#chapter-2-the-nature-of-functions)